# Convolution or addition? Proper way to model overlapping absorption line profiles

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, absorption, fluorescence

Suppose you obtain a measured spectral line shape (let's call it 'envelope') which appears as a skewed/asymmetric voigt profile. You know physically that the envelope line profile has this skew because of two overlapping absorption profiles: one that is dominant (giving the predominant voigt-like shape to the envelope), and another, slightly displaced in wavelength, which is non-dominant (gives skew to wings of voigt-like envelope). If you want to fit this envelope to a double-voigt model (say, with lmfit python package), would you model the spectra to be voigt1 + voigt2 (addition of overlapped voigt profiles) or voigt1 * voigt2 (a convolution of overlapped voigt profiles)? I am having a hard time wrapping my head around which mathematical operation represents the observed physics. Thank you!

[shown here is an example 'envelope' spectrum as a skewed voigt, and an example where two component voigts can explain the skew in the envelope]

[image: Measured line profile I refer to as the envelope]

[image: Envelope explainable by presence of two underlying absorption profiles]

Comment: This could be linked to the fact that the pdf of the sum of 2 random variables is the convolution of their 2 pdf (?)

Comment: Maybe the line profile corresponding to energy eigenstate f were obtained by projecting it on the kinetic energy and potential energy eigenfunctions and then convoluted together .

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you are measuring two independendent spectral lines whose finite profiles overlap. If that is the case, they should be modelled as an additive [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) (by the superposition principle), because you are simply measuring the sum of intensities from one plus the other. The correct answer is therefore `voigt1 + voigt2`. What you seem to have written down for a "convolution" also doesn't look like a convolution to me, but rather a product of the amplitudes. Convolutions only come into play if some of your signal (but crucially not all of it) is shifted along the x-axis by some amount.

I hope this helps! Let me know if I have misunderstood anything, or something isn't clear.

Comment: Thank you for addressing my question, your answer already gives me more insight, but perhaps I should elaborate. Technically the two voigts I mention come from the same transition in the same atomic species (i.e. in theory there should be only one voigt). However there are two populations of this atom; one population is of much lower temperature and is decoupled from a rotating plasma, and the other population is high temperature and rotating (coupled to plasma). Therefore, the displacement of the voigts comes from a doppler shift of the 'hot' population (which sounds to me like convolution)

Comment: @kl_physicist if they are distinct spectra coming from distinct atoms, it should still be a superposition. It would be a convolution if the emission from the spectra than underwent another process that had the second spectral shape.

Comment: Thank you @Señor O for the further explanation. I see now that it should be additive superposition. So for example, if the physical spectrum should be observed to be voigt-like, but then my instrument response function were for whatever reason a step-function, I would have recorded a spectrum that would be a convolution of a voigt and step-function. Whereas, if I measured overlapping spectra with a perfect instrument—one absorption that was voigt and another that was gaussian—then the resulting spectrum would be superposition of gauss + voigt. Correct?

Comment: @kl_physicist that sounds right to me, instrument response is usually (with some exceptions I'm sure) a text book example of when to use a convolution.